# WPF treeview item type variable

Tags: wpf, vb.net, autocad

I am using WPF type user control in autocad API.

> Dim newnode As System.Windows.Controls.TreeViewItem
>           newnode = mypalette2.treeview1.Items.Add(e.DBObject.GetType().ToString())

but it gives error "value of integer can not be converted to treviewitem"

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Add() returns the index at which the item was added to the "Items" collection, not the TreeViewItem object itself.  Use the index to get the TreeViewItem out of the Items collection:

Untested code, but this should do it (don't write it like this - make it cleaner ;)):

```
Dim newnode As System.Windows.Controls.TreeViewItem newnode = mypalette2.treeview1.Items(mypalette2.treeview1.Items.Add(e.DBObject.GetType().ToString()))
```

Ideally you'd first check to make sure Add() did not return -1, which means the Add operation failed.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer:

```
Dim newNode As New TreeNode
newNode.Text = e.DBObject.GetType().Name
newNode.Tag = e.DBObject.ObjectId
_treeView.Nodes.Add(newNode)
```

And would recommend you set the Tag property with the ObjectId of the entity, otherwise you cannot refer to this item (on the tree view) later on on your code.